# Setting initial values to parameters when fitting a curve with lmfit

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, lmfit

I'm using a composite model, two Gaussians, to fit a curve with `lmfit` and the results of the fit seem to be quite dependent on the initial values I'm giving. What is the best way of setting initial parameters? I know of three different methods with `lmfit`: `add`, `set` and `set_param_hint`, but I don't fully understand the differences. Documentation suggests that `set_param_hint` is a good way of doing this but I'd like to know the difference with the other approaches.

This is an example of my code using to different methods (`add` and `set`) to illustrate the confusion:

```
from lmfit import Model, Parameters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x_val = [4460.1758349164, 4460.375833832813, 4460.575832749225, 4460.775831665638, 4460.975830582051, 4461.175829498463, 4461.375828414875, 4461.575827331288, 4461.775826247701, 4461.975825164113, 4462.175824080526, 4462.375822996938, 4462.57582191335, 4462.775820829764, 4462.975819746176, 4463.1758186625875, 4463.375817579001, 4463.575816495413, 4463.775815411826, 4463.975814328239, 4464.175813244651, 4464.375812161064, 4464.575811077476, 4464.775809993889, 4464.9758089103025, 4465.175807826714, 4465.375806743126, 4465.57580565954, 4465.775804575952, 4465.975803492364, 4466.175802408777, 4466.375801325189, 4466.575800241602, 4466.775799158015, 4466.975798074427, 4467.175796990839, 4467.375795907252, 4467.575794823664, 4467.7757937400775, 4467.97579265649, 4468.175791572902, 4468.3757904893155, 4468.575789405728, 4468.77578832214, 4468.975787238553, 4469.175786154965, 4469.375785071377, 4469.5757839877915, 4469.775782904203, 4469.975781820615, 4470.175780737029, 4470.37577965344, 4470.575778569853, 4470.775777486266, 4470.975776402678, 4471.1757753190905, 4471.375774235503, 4471.575773151916, 4471.7757720683285, 4471.975770984741, 4472.175769901153, 4472.375768817566, 4472.575767733979, 4472.775766650391, 4472.9757655668045, 4473.175764483216, 4473.375763399628, 4473.575762316042, 4473.775761232454, 4473.975760148866, 4474.175759065279, 4474.375757981692, 4474.575756898104, 4474.775755814518, 4474.975754730929, 4475.1757536473415, 4475.375752563754, 4475.575751480167, 4475.77575039658, 4475.975749312992, 4476.175748229404, 4476.3757471458175, 4476.57574606223, 4476.775744978642, 4476.975743895055, 4477.175742811467, 4477.375741727879, 4477.575740644294, 4477.775739560705, 4477.9757384771165, 4478.17573739353, 4478.375736309943, 4478.575735226355, 4478.775734142768, 4478.97573305918, 4479.175731975593, 4479.375730892006, 4479.575729808418, 4479.7757287248305, 4479.975727641243, 4480.175726557655, 4480.375725474069, 4480.575724390481, 4480.775723306892, 4480.975722223307, 4481.175721139718, 4481.375720056131, 4481.575718972544, 4481.775717888956, 4481.975716805368, 4482.175715721783, 4482.375714638194, 4482.5757135546055, 4482.77571247102, 4482.975711387431, 4483.175710303844, 4483.375709220257, 4483.575708136668, 4483.7757070530815, 4483.975705969494, 4484.175704885907, 4484.3757038023205, 4484.575702718732, 4484.775701635144, 4484.975700551557]
y_val = [1.0438815599549134, 0.9861559707471772, 1.0056426645990315, 1.0016074526378649, 1.0452997007422666, 0.992212205281684, 1.0365215397316232, 1.0218869075138342, 1.0055580715537948, 1.0156218890501965, 1.028214904229718, 0.9935787796492273, 1.02364139796149, 1.0179358129807576, 1.035762676388034, 1.049932333954558, 1.0402954847373662, 1.0169711103176595, 1.0340240575460198, 1.049747768424791, 1.0175400582158902, 1.0103838602023636, 1.0680006544649665, 0.975519363154844, 1.0202812597671398, 0.9695222898779196, 1.0052738395140506, 1.0053855702044892, 0.9935941046265898, 0.986614047747308, 0.9986655992818708, 0.9999356062287996, 1.0240484329659438, 0.9819990493350282, 1.000327008341581, 0.9717165926477822, 0.9879546941197598, 0.9842935196212136, 1.0222486380060392, 0.975275958755044, 1.0498618707695202, 1.025608170066069, 0.9909686718827492, 0.975939608797198, 0.9467728492315236, 0.9480619167488604, 0.9600094590732424, 0.9636132733406744, 0.9944894010124092, 0.9426361826831244, 0.9782473212039978, 0.9378327202091502, 0.9488207621805942, 0.9669396283466724, 0.9432847772067492, 0.9015761099378126, 0.9135968691755808, 0.8939703886252973, 0.8573607070423116, 0.868161237954455, 0.8849968824099054, 0.885539805042943, 0.844515618445441, 0.8842305221856582, 0.8877296440122721, 0.8821343557372545, 0.9075013206055316, 0.8660876250948828, 0.9127519356948968, 0.8952841088988195, 0.9602437689940024, 1.0375435216069926, 1.1326450855548746, 1.2528373417955827, 1.359064567678794, 1.7397790583320276, 2.2955575263013603, 2.6313330486608075, 2.7696361971739485, 2.2290943507722045, 1.5299780348545342, 1.1265789292075985, 0.9761209131908825, 0.9552781525369406, 0.9872235913023412, 0.9554892446527146, 0.9693081918466234, 0.9565660500653812, 0.9460822542921022, 0.9266113291876116, 0.9704238862428936, 0.8915634335508363, 0.9158114443978326, 0.9466235269126626, 0.9451751549645016, 0.946265616542422, 0.9367300273679332, 0.971583009744108, 0.9435038781374095, 0.9892258250694016, 0.9754689843339546, 0.9578096187257352, 0.9649331079033204, 0.9709409505255512, 0.9818618967434926, 0.9732673864230984, 0.9970556441582832, 0.9810274934718626, 0.939447766493294, 1.0112673683488067, 1.0191757378152404, 0.9835438808599056, 0.985619193341479, 0.9862022169399436, 1.0458502824889473, 0.9594215029321304, 0.9971740675615232, 0.9974173269531228, 0.9955615254192632, 1.03531504592408, 1.0077373609120324, 1.0009705059358802, 1.0206465226122023, 0.9591259867321692, 1.0148009048782651]
err = [0.0356014742203398, 0.028023844164620268, 0.02706632229192564, 0.026921086598994004, 0.03404330335778127, 0.03225575706454388, 0.032951103033851084, 0.02550825680398673, 0.029497494361785826, 0.025198158411558855, 0.03492983187381606, 0.03163083328614311, 0.027704308525917317, 0.03494848818894923, 0.030014846715378605, 0.035741193441217865, 0.03078218636873445, 0.023901828310539986, 0.03628052312062977, 0.035025392619838884, 0.03976648591093106, 0.02780543058799098, 0.040944290884658216, 0.034099200916427784, 0.03205306075906642, 0.03326464028563125, 0.02337626476347709, 0.026083179277841928, 0.028218666012639764, 0.04596683621166614, 0.03305076066644353, 0.028735271103684058, 0.03966961113288402, 0.029082468902683317, 0.028285569241373782, 0.031786755430356486, 0.024404779108853858, 0.026129373614987225, 0.03286225269330064, 0.0337885577191429, 0.037435419977679456, 0.027487698789152224, 0.02431364360404831, 0.03695118040711042, 0.05126648287442151, 0.04107233842769607, 0.03979475798462972, 0.03740966627043441, 0.030822212943554483, 0.05058778089333995, 0.03679756266194399, 0.06998625264367124, 0.03794562219242631, 0.03310200401794181, 0.05331291012493153, 0.07986441365482183, 0.06900775599719644, 0.08219705262724887, 0.105874487190267, 0.10342988581359616, 0.08019517918681268, 0.08692292530550771, 0.113978355113441, 0.09103658535785254, 0.08330700273089763, 0.09023708512793886, 0.06817086680024753, 0.09733919241124256, 0.06544890074726599, 0.0734814660643719, 0.03886987577445243, 0.033151154927677444, 0.07391828687885042, 0.12902165265322205, 0.16726327412564035, 0.2647359446458325, 0.4179242572687573, 0.4541710636471308, 0.37629500747418, 0.3240957615905829, 0.2051963217492506, 0.07266588290723769, 0.036843269718234525, 0.05208312696082423, 0.026365044379277364, 0.04304862993377523, 0.03843764665504956, 0.04830679502266177, 0.057360927302557374, 0.06550536976828003, 0.03740542151100047, 0.08629363539797757, 0.0592656471636982, 0.0498517781492637, 0.04573315868341099, 0.04517963641752231, 0.056639635044659624, 0.03210377504774208, 0.04591194405625765, 0.0270964657791688, 0.04062592174152552, 0.039282823305607964, 0.034139260725464984, 0.030730966608705536, 0.0257602056376013, 0.03354067520866908, 0.02882918823621897, 0.02923878376561263, 0.0564366148759929, 0.036253452623873764, 0.02504495217929072, 0.040091125177588, 0.02658634779690779, 0.02667635918064909, 0.03370366542143037, 0.039955314845191145, 0.03135622152872908, 0.059506780695663314, 0.025254987757541952, 0.038034923152503126, 0.02883708074109163, 0.02606771741119524, 0.039180311098300204, 0.04173873330363966, 0.024621574626190273]

def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    "1-d gaussian: gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)"
    return 1 - amp*np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 /(2*(wid/2.355)**2))

def nebu(x, amp, cen, wid):
    "1-d gaussian: gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)"
    return -amp*np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 /(2*(wid/2.355)**2))

gauss = Model(gaussian)
pars = Parameters()
pars.add('amp', value=0.2, min=0.01, max=1. )
#pars.add('cen', value=x_val[argmax(y_val)], min=4472, max=4478)
pars.add('cen', value=4475, min=4470, max=4480)
pars.add('wid', value=5, min=1, max=10.)                

gauss2 = Model(nebu, prefix='neb_')
pars.update(gauss2.make_params())                                        

pars['neb_amp'].set(-1, min=-4, max=-0.1)
#pars['neb_cen'].set(x_val[argmax(y_val)], min=4470, max=4480)
pars['neb_cen'].set(4475, min=4470, max=4480)
pars['neb_wid'].set(0.8, min=0.1, max=2.)

mod = gauss + gauss2

result = mod.fit(y_val, pars, x=x_val, weights=[1./x for x in err])
comp = result.eval_components(result.params, x=x_val)

print(result.fit_report())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))    
plt.plot(x_val, y_val, 'k-', lw=2, label='data')
plt.plot(x_val, result.init_fit, '--', c='gray', label='initial pars')
plt.plot(x_val, result.best_fit, 'r-', lw=2, label='model fit')
plt.plot(x_val, comp['gaussian'], '--', c='limegreen', lw=2, label='gauss')
plt.plot(x_val, 1+comp['neb_'], '--', c='orange', lw=2, label='gauss2')                            
plt.legend(loc='best',fontsize=10, handlelength=2, frameon=False)                               

plt.show()
```

And here is the fit report:

```
[[Model]]
    (Model(gaussian) + Model(nebu, prefix='neb_'))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 155
    # data points      = 125
    # variables        = 6
    chi-square         = 66.8949742
    reduced chi-square = 0.56214264
    Akaike info crit   = -66.1487371
    Bayesian info crit = -49.1788547
[[Variables]]
    amp:      0.07859727 +/- 0.01341948 (17.07%) (init = 0.2)
    cen:      4474.64017 +/- 0.37950199 (0.01%) (init = 4477)
    wid:      8.08798219 +/- 0.87892008 (10.87%) (init = 5)
    neb_amp: -1.44779784 +/- 0.14587605 (10.08%) (init = -1)
    neb_cen:  4475.51782 +/- 0.02445057 (0.00%) (init = 4475)
    neb_wid:  1.06240785 +/- 0.05036105 (4.74%) (init = 0.8)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(amp, wid)         = -0.721
    C(neb_amp, neb_wid) =  0.652
    C(amp, neb_wid)     =  0.559
    C(wid, neb_wid)     = -0.373
    C(neb_cen, neb_wid) = -0.163
    C(neb_amp, neb_cen) = -0.150
    C(cen, neb_cen)     =  0.138
    C(amp, neb_amp)     =  0.132
    C(amp, neb_cen)     = -0.132
    C(wid, neb_cen)     =  0.123
```

Choosing different initial values in some cases can change the result of the fit (e.g. cen=4472), so I'm wondering if this can be related to the method for giving the initial values or is just the noise and errors of the data that prevent the fit from doing a better job.

Comment: I have an example of fitting a double Lorentzian peak equation to Raman spectroscopy of carbon nanotubes here https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/ramanspectroscopyfit and it uses scipy's genetic algorithm module scipy.optimize.differential_evolution to estimate the initial parameters for fitting. This scipy module might be of similar use in this case.

Comment: This is a nice example, thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways to specify initial values for parameters in lmfit.

`Parameters.add()` adds a `Parameter` to the `Parameters` ordered dict.  When adding a `Parameter` in this way, you can set an initial value and set other attributes (especially `min`, `max`, `vary`, and `expr`).

`Parameter.set()` sets one or more attributes (`value`, `min`, `max`, `vary`, and `expr`) for an existing `Parameter`.  You can also just set these attributes explicitly, as with

```
pars['neb_wid'].value = 0.8
```

Those all work on `Parameter` objects and the `Parameters` collection.

In addition, a `lmfit.Model` will have a `make_params()` method that creates a `Parameters` collection for that model.  You use that in your example.  This method can take initial values for any of the parameters, or you can modify the generated `Parameters` after they are created`.

A `Model` may have one or more parameter hints that help the `Model` create its `Parameters`. Parameter hints may include an initial value but are often used to set a boundary or expression, so that one can express "for this Model, the parameter `foo` must be positive, and the parameter `bar` must be `= 2*foo - baz`.
In this way, parameter hints *belong to the model*.

Those remarks are all about the mechanics of *how* to set initial values for a parameter.  Deciding what those initial values should be is an entirely different matter.  Using a global solver like differential evolution or (probably better) AMPGO or brute force stepping over a limited number of options (all of these are available within lmfit) may be useful, but can be time-consuming.

For sure, having two overlapping Gaussians (both of yours have `value=4475, min=4470, max=4480`) with widths that are the same order of magnitude will be difficult to distinguish, and can lead to instabilities in the fit.   Do you really expect to have a superposition of Gaussians with nearly the same center (but not the same, otherwise you'd constrain them to be equal), sigmas that are not *that* different, and amplitudes with different signs?   If so, yeah that seems like a hard problem to me!

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I just have one doubt, if I want to set an expression as a hint for a  model, as in your example with `foo` and `bar`, would you recommend me to give the initial values _in_ the hint, or, set the initial values as I did with `Parameters` and then set the `expr` as a hint to the `Model`? Regarding the Gaussians, unfortunately that's the way the data is, if you run my example you can take a quick look. There is a difference between the 2 centres, but it changes from data set to data set, so I can't fix it, even so, I think `lmfit` does a quite good job!

Comment: @JVR an expression hint should not need an initial value. Its value will always be calculated from the other parameters.    The two Gaussians in your data do not overlap that much -- you could use `value=4476, min=4472` for the center of the positive peak and `value=4472, max=4476` for the center of the negative peak.  That should give much less chance for the fit to confuse the two peaks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll do that and I'll take a look at the global solvers too.